# How many letters can copy in a single instance?

Tags: operating-systems

We're always use Copy & Paste function in various OS's . Now, I want to know how many bytes can copy in a single copy command. Can I copy entire letters from Oxford dictionary on a single "**CTRL + C**" ?

Comment: This depends on the amount of system memory you have.

Comment: Are you asking what the maximum capacity of the system clipboard is? If so, what operating system are you interested in? (And your statement that "we'[ve] always use[d] copy and paste function in various OS[e]s" is provably wrong. Even if we limit our "always" to "for as long as personal computers have existed", there remain many computers and OSes that had no native copy-paste functionality. [DOSKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY) and similar utilities were a major usability improvement back in the day, but ate a fair chunk of precious RAM so not everyone always used them.)

Comment: @Ramhound - means if I've 1GB system memory , may I copy that much amount of letters in a single CTRL + C action ?

Comment: @Ramhound: That's a lie – servers with terabytes of RAM already [exist](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/enterprise/387196/intel-xeon-e7-v2-servers-support-6tb-of-ram) and are in use; just not exactly cheap.

Comment: @grawity - I will take your word for it.  Doesn't change the fact the author likely has a server with 500GB or 1TB of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can vary between operating systems, but usually the clipboard size is limited to the amount of total memory a single process can allocate, so it depends on how much RAM you have, as well as the CPU architecture (processes on 32-bit systems are usually limited to 2 or 4 GB each).

This is true at least for Windows and X11-using systems; I haven't researched others.

Of course, you still need to have enough memory for the OS and the programs themselves; if you only have 1 GB of RAM, you obviously cannot use *all of it* for the clipboard.

Comment: Won't clipboard memory be paged like any other memory allocated to a process? In which case the limit would be the virtual memory size minus the other memory used for this process and the total used by other processes.

Comment: Do you mean virtual memory as in swap/page file, or virtual memory as in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)?

Comment: I did have paging in mind.

Comment: In that case, sure, the clipboard contents can be swapped/paged out like a regular memory allocation. But the total size of any single allocation is still limited to the virtual memory area (i.e. the address range) available to a process.